# How can i separate values in an array like this..[(1,3),(2,5),(4,8),(9,10),(5,6),(4,7),(7,10)]?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, collections, key-value

For example, you have array of entry and exit date of patients(entry, exit)
like [(1,3),(2,5),(4,8),(9,10),(5,6),(4,7),(7,10)] and i want to separate each elements ..
Help me!

Comment: Have you considered using a 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to separate the array and save it into 2 lists called as `entry` and `exit`

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArraySeparation {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] patient = {1,3,2,5,4,8,9,10};
        int n = patient.length;

        ArrayList<Integer> entry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> exit = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int i = 0;
        while(i < n) 
        {
           if(i != n)
                entry.add(patient[i]);
           i+=2;

        }i = 1;
        while(i < n)
        {
            if(i != n)
                 exit.add(patient[i]);
            i+=2;
        }

        System.out.println("Entry List:");
        for(int l:entry) System.out.print(l + " ");

        System.out.println("\nExit List:");
        for(int l:exit) System.out.print(l + " ");
    }
}

/*
 * Output:
 * Entry List:
 * 1 2 4 9
 * Exit List:
 * 3 5 8 10
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Python zip and Unzip concept we can separate it easily.
for example :

```
a=  [(1,3),(2,5),(4,8),(9,10),(5,6),(4,7),(7,10)]
b=[]

for start_d, end_d in a:
    max_d = end_d - start_d
    b.append(max_d)
    print(f'Duration of stays max_d: {max_d}')
b.sort()    
print(b) 
print(b[(b.__len__()-1)])
```

and output

```
Duration of stays max_d: 2
Duration of stays max_d: 3
Duration of stays max_d: 4
Duration of stays max_d: 1
Duration of stays max_d: 1
Duration of stays max_d: 3
Duration of stays max_d: 3
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
4// max-m day stay
```